# XSLT 1.0: Walking and filtering a tree backwards

Tags: xslt, tree, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<things>
  <thing name="Foo" available="yes"/>
  <thing name="Bar" available="no"/>
  <thing name="Baz" available="yes">
    <parent name="Foo"/>
    <parent name="Bar"/>
  </thing>
  <thing name="Qux" available="no">
    <parent name="Foo"/>
    <parent name="Bar"/>
  </thing>
  <thing name="Waldo" available="yes">
    <parent name="Foo"/>
    <parent name="Bar"/>
    <parent name="Baz"/>
    <parent name="Qux"/>
  </thing>
</things>
```

This represent a structure like the following:

- Foo

  - Baz

    - Waldo
  - Qux

    - Waldo
  - Waldo
- Bar

  - Baz

    - Waldo
  - Qux

    - Waldo
  - Waldo

The actual XML is quite large and the nesting is deep. Unavaliable things can be anywhere. There are no loops (things that have themselves as ancestors).

Now I want to generate all possible paths to Waldo, filtering out the paths containing things that are not available. Something like the following result is what I'm looking for:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#Foo">Foo</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#Baz">Baz</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>Waldo</b>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#Foo">Foo</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <b>Waldo</b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That is:

- Foo

  - Baz

    - **Waldo**
- Foo

  - **Waldo**

Starting from a leaf node, looking up the tree, generating all possible paths while ignoring unavailable paths got me stumped. Any insights, prose, pseudocode or XSLT is much appreciated!

Comment: Contradiction: According to the XMl, waldo isn't a child of baz -- please, edit the question and correct.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="thing" use="parent/@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
         <things>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="thing[not(parent)]"/>
         </things>
   </xsl:variable>


   <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*"
                        mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="thing">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', @name)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="pass2"
      match="*[not(@name = 'Waldo' or .//*[@name='Waldo'])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<things>
    <thing name="Foo" available="yes"/>
    <thing name="Bar" available="no"/>
    <thing name="Baz" available="yes">
        <parent name="Foo"/>
        <parent name="Bar"/>
    </thing>
    <thing name="Qux" available="no">
        <parent name="Foo"/>
        <parent name="Bar"/>
    </thing>
    <thing name="Waldo" available="yes">
        <parent name="Foo"/>
        <parent name="Bar"/>
        <parent name="Qux"/>
    </thing>
</things>
```

**produces a result that contains only "branches" containing "waldo":**

```
<things>
   <thing name="Foo" available="yes">
      <thing name="Qux" available="no">
         <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
      </thing>
      <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
   </thing>
   <thing name="Bar" available="no">
      <thing name="Qux" available="no">
         <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
      </thing>
      <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
   </thing>
</things>
```

It is left as an exercise to the reader to transform this to whatever final HTML format is needed.

**Explanation**:

1. This is a two-pass transformation.
2. The first pass constructs a tree in which the parent-child relationship is expressed explicitly.
3. The second pass is an identity rule, overlaid by a template with empty body ("deleting" template) for subtrees that don't contain an `thing` with attribute `name` with string-value `"Waldo"`.

**The result of the first pass is**:

```
<things>
   <thing name="Foo" available="yes">
      <thing name="Baz" available="yes"/>
      <thing name="Qux" available="no">
         <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
      </thing>
      <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
   </thing>
   <thing name="Bar" available="no">
      <thing name="Baz" available="yes"/>
      <thing name="Qux" available="no">
         <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
      </thing>
      <thing name="Waldo" available="yes"/>
   </thing>
</things>
```

The second pass strips off two `<thing name="Baz" available="yes"/>` elements to produce the final result.

Comment: Great! Adding a predicate [@available='yes'] to the identity transform also removes branches containing unavailable things and makes it do exactly what I wanted. Paths to Waldo that are blocked by unavailable things are then removed from the result.

Comment: @pugmarx, Thank you for your appreciation.